# How to convert Arraylist in java to lpwstr in c using jni

Tags: java, c++, arraylist, java-native-interface

I am passing an ArrayList to c++ using JNI. I want to convert it to LPWSTR* type. But i receive the arraylist as jobject. How can i convert this?

Comment: ArrayList of what ?  Strings ?  How do you want to convert them into the LPWSTR ? I mean, logically. Concatenation or something else ?

Comment: If you really want to convert it to LPWSTR* than see above comment by Victor Latypov.
If you meant LPWSTR** (pointer to array of strings) then just converting ArrayList to standard array of Strings (String[]) will do.

Comment: I have arraylist of strings. I want it to be converted to LPWSTR*. If i have 3 strings in arraylist, in c++ i want it as LPWSTR array or LPWSTR* with the 3 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start. I'm not sure about some of the conversions, hope others would help.

You have an object. Get the methods for JNI and call them. It's simple.

The following code sample may help to get started.

```
// parameter
jobject YourJObjectRepresentingArrayList;

// I suppose you have the JNIEnv somehow
JNIEnv* env;

// use the Array list
ArrayList_class       = env->FindClass( "java/util/ArrayList" );

    // to conver jobject to jstring
    jmethodID caster = env->GetMethodID(ArrayList_class, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

// get two methods
Get_method            = env->GetMethodID( ArrayList_class, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object" );
Size_method           = env->GetMethodID( ArrayList_class, "size", "()I" );

// call java.lang.ArrayList.get()
int NumElts = env->CallIntMethod(YourJObjectRepresentingArrayList, ArrayList_class, Size_method);

// allocate output array
LPWSTR* Out = new LPWSTR[NumElts];

// fetch all the items
for(int i = 0 ; i < NumElts ; i++)
{
    // call java.lang.ArrayList.get(int index) method
    // Not sure about the parameter passing here
    jobject Tmp = env->CallObjectMethod(YourJObjectRepresentingArrayList, Get_method, i);

    jstring Str = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(Tmp, caster);

    // get the length
    int StrLen = env->GetStringLength(env, Str);

    Out[i] = new wchar_t[StrLen];

    const char* SourceUTF = env->GetStringChars(env, Str);

    // store the string - not sure about UTF-16/UTF-8 here. It is OS-dependant.
    // MultiByteToWideChar or iconv on POSIX
    ConvertUTF8ToWChar(Out[i], SourceUTF);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(s, SourceUTF);
}

// done
```